# Json file starts with b-

Tags: python, json, sockets

I am streaming data from a sensor using socket library in Json format, and trying to parse it and load it into Database. 
When I print the stream I get this Json in this format:

```
b'[{"metadata":{"timezone":{"location":"Etc/UTC"},"serial_number":"00:07:32:52:09:fc","device_type":"SPIDER"},"timestamp":"2019-08-29T13:53:05.895Z","framenumber":"2290718","tracked_objects":[{"id":2592,"is_at_border":true,"type":"PERSON","position":{"x":233,"y":262,"type":"FOOT","coordinate_system":"PROCESSING_IN_PIXEL"},"person_data":{"height":1728}}]}]'
```

Based on my research prefix b stands for the byte type. So when I try to parse it with code below:

```
while True:
    message, address = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    message = message.upper()

    # loading json file.
    objs_json = json.loads(message)
    # using if looop to prevent script of trying to to parse data without any object being tracked.
    if "tracked_objects" in objs_json:
        # Parsing json file with json_normalize object
        objs_df = json_normalize(
            objs_json, record_path='tracked_objects',
            meta=[['metadata', 'serial_number'], 'timestamp']
        )
        # Renaming columns
        objs_df = objs_df.rename(
            columns={
                "id": "object_id", "position.x": "x_pos", 
                "position.y": "y_pos", "person_data.height": "height",
                "metadata.serial_number": "serial_number",
                "timestamp": "timestamp"
            }
        )
        # Selecting columns of interest
        objs_df = objs_df.loc[:, ["timestamp", "serial_number", "object_id", "x_pos", "y_pos", "height"]]
        # Writting the data into SQlite db
        objs_df.to_sql('data_object', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
    # In case there is no tracks, print No Tracks in console.
    else:
        print("No Tracks")
```

I get this error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/ProRail-PMS/Test_Spider2.py", line 20, in <module>
    objs_json = json.loads(message)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 215 (char 214)
```

However if I save that data into json file and remove the prefix b my parsing code works. 
How do i go around this so when I receive the data from socket library I want to be able to parse it and feed it into database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first I wanted to comment that it works for me, but then I noticed how you get the message and what you do with it:

Remove `message = message.upper()`:

```
>>> message = b'[{"metadata":{"timezone":{"location":"Etc/UTC"},"serial_number":"00:07:32:52:09:fc","device_type":"SPIDER"},"timestamp":"2019-08-29T13:53:05.895Z","framenumber":"2290718","tracked_objects":[{"id":2592,"is_at_border":true,"type":"PERSON","position":{"x":233,"y":262,"type":"FOOT","coordinate_system":"PROCESSING_IN_PIXEL"},"person_data":{"height":1728}}]}]'
>>> json.loads(message)
[{'metadata': {'timezone': {'location': 'Etc/UTC'}, 'serial_number': '00:07:32:52:09:fc', 'device_type': 'SPIDER'}, 'timestamp': '2019-08-29T13:53:05.895Z', 'framenumber': '2290718', 'tracked_objects': [{'id': 2592, 'is_at_border': True, 'type': 'PERSON', 'position': {'x': 233, 'y': 262, 'type': 'FOOT', 'coordinate_system': 'PROCESSING_IN_PIXEL'}, 'person_data': {'height': 1728}}]}]
>>
>>
>>> message = message.upper()
b'[{"METADATA":{"TIMEZONE":{"LOCATION":"ETC/UTC"},"SERIAL_NUMBER":"00:07:32:52:09:FC","DEVICE_TYPE":"SPIDER"},"TIMESTAMP":"2019-08-29T13:53:05.895Z","FRAMENUMBER":"2290718","TRACKED_OBJECTS":[{"ID":2592,"IS_AT_BORDER":TRUE,"TYPE":"PERSON","POSITION":{"X":233,"Y":262,"TYPE":"FOOT","COORDINATE_SYSTEM":"PROCESSING_IN_PIXEL"},"PERSON_DATA":{"HEIGHT":1728}}]}]'
>>> json.loads(message)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 217 (char 216)
>>> message[217:]
b'RUE,"TYPE":"PERSON","POSITION":{"X":233,"Y":262,"TYPE":"FOOT","COORDINATE_SYSTEM":"PROCESSING_IN_PIXEL"},"PERSON_DATA":{"HEIGHT":1728}}]}]'
```

Your `upper` breaks the True value that is unquoted (because it's a boolean, not a string). ;)

Comment: so with your suggestion i am able to avoide that error however it is not parsing my data. I am getting "No Tracks" message as it seems to not finding the  ""tracked_objects" within Json file. Did i write that part correctly?

Comment: Be wary of types - your json is a single-element list with a dict inside. Do `objs_json = json.loads(message)[0]` to get the dictionary. Then your code will see "tracked_objects" part. Dunno about the rest. I don't have time to analyse your whole code. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Imported it into Notepad++ since the JSON file is of type byte. Saved it out as JSON and it saved normally as a standard JSON file. Used Python json.load(f) to bring it in from my drive and then it can be used.

Comment: Hi Bob, welcome to SO! Please read up on [answering questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before writing your next answer :)